# How to control delay loops in assembly

Tags: assembly, time, x86, dos, tasm

I'm in a struggle timing 3 loops in assembly.
The first loop is supposed to be working for 10 sec, then jump into the second loop which should be executed for 2 seconds. The third is to be working 10 more seconds.

The main idea is to build a traffic light. Each led connected to the parallel port should turn on a different period of time using TASM.
Red :10 sec.
Red & orange : 2 sec
Green : 10 sec
and then get back to red again .. and so on

Any help please?
I tried using `INT 21h`, function `2Ch` to time each loop .

My teacher told me it would work out just fine this way . 
yet, none of the LEDs turned on when I tried executing the code .

my code :

```
.model small
.stack 100
.code

Loop_time :
mov ah,2ch
int 21h
mov ax,003ch 
mul cl
mov ch,0000h
add bx,cx
mov dl,dh
mov dh,0
add bx,dx
push bx 

loop_red :

mov ah,2ch
int 21h
mov ax,003ch 
mul cl
mov ch,0000h
add ax,cx
mov dl,dh
mov dh,0
add ax,dx
add ax,0ah
pop bx 
cmp ax,bx
jg loop_redorange 
mov DX, 378h
mov AL, 1
out DX,AL 


loop_redorange:
mov ah,2ch
int 21h
mov ax,003ch 
mul cl
mov ch,0000h
add ax,cx
mov dl,dh
mov dh,0
add ax,dx
add ax,0ch  
pop bx 
cmp ax,bx
jg loop_green
mov DX, 378h
mov AL,3
out DX,AL 


loop_green : 

mov ah,2ch
int 21h
mov ax,003ch 
mul cl
mov ch,0000h
add ax,cx
mov dl,dh
mov dh,0
add ax,dx
add ax,20h 
pop bx 
cmp ax,bx 
jg loop_red
mov DX, 378h
mov AL, 4
out DX,AL 


mov ah,4ch  
int 21h
end
```

Comment: So what you actually want is a delay-loop or equivalent, not timing a single instruction or measuring performance.

Comment: Yes ! exactly . Any help with that ? My code had no errors , but yet didn't work lol !

Comment: We can't help you with code that you don't post.  An [mcve] to show what you're trying to do would make this a better question.

Comment: I really appreciate your cooperation .. excuse my ignorance I'm new to the whole thing :)

Comment: 'int ah,2ch' should be 'mov ah,2ch', shouldn't it ?

Comment: "but it didn't work" is still not a problem description.  See [ask] and [mcve].  You should be describing exactly what it does currently do, and anything useful you see with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

hello the loop is:

```
.model small
.data
  endloop db ?
.stack 100
.code
   mov dx,378h
   mov ah,2ch
   int 21h
   mov endloop,dh
   add endloop,0ah ; for 10 second
   cmp endloop,59  ; if endloop <= 60 then ok
   jle loop_red
   sub endloop,60 ; convert virtual second in real second
 loop_red: mov ax,003ch 
   mul cl
   add dx, cl
   mov bx,dx
   add bx,000Ah
   cmp dx,bx
   jg loop_redorange 
   mov AL, 0001h
   out DX,AL
   xor ax,ax
   mov ah,2ch
   int 21h
   cmp endloop,dh ; if current second == (begin second + 10) exit
   jl loop_red
```

$ for other loop you must only change this loop.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you pointed out what you changed, and explained why.  SO is about questions and answers that can help future readers with similar problems, so explanations are at least as important as the code.   code-dump questions and answers are both bad.

Comment: you can [edit] your answer instead of posting a new one.  But since you did that already, maybe you should delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

good point 
for doing a loop you must have initial point and endpoint.
for this
i have inset a variable (endloop) that are inizialized with endpoint
line 
   mov ah,2ch
   int 21h ;load a time system
   mov endloop,dh ;save the second into variable.
   add endloop,0ah ;calculation end value for loop.
now can be that value of endloop is over 60 second (0..59)

```
cmp endloop,59  ; if endloop <= 60 then ok
jle loop_red ;not need normalized go to loop
```

$so i must normalized endloop

```
Sub endloop,60 ; normalize endloop new range (0..59)
```

$since we have calculated the end loop point the seconds beds will be the initial ones.
so we can start with our loop
we do what we have to do (label loop_red)
at ending i check if the loop is finish.
this i do so:

```
xor ax,ax ; clear ax because is needed for system call
mov ah,2ch ; now read how many time is passed.
int 21h
cmp endloop,dh ; the time is ending ?
jl loop_red ; no repeat a loop
;yes i can take dh (second for next loop)
```

$ i hope that now is more clear then before.

Comment: that's some great info ! .. Really appreciate it , I'll try it and tell you what happens .

Comment: I've updated my code to what I ended up with since yesterday. what problems does it have ?